# CloudFlare credentials missing when using lego to create "Let's Encrypt" ssl cert

Tags: cloudflare

I am trying to generate a server ssl certificate. The DNS is maintained on Cloudflare.

The [`lego`](https://github.com/xenolf/lego)'s help suggests the following syntax

```
CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=anthony@mycompany.com \
CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=ABCD1234 \
sudo lego --dns cloudflare --domains about.mycompany.com \
  --email anthony@mycompany.com --path="/etc/lego" run
```

However the command returns the following error:

```
2018/04/19 02:19:45 CloudFlare credentials missing
```

It turns out the environment variables are not captured by the lego.

If I put the above (minus `sudo`) in a shell script file (says `getcert.sh`)

```
CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=anthony@mycompany.com \
CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=ABCD1234 \
lego --dns cloudflare --domains about.mycompany.com \
  --email anthony@mycompany.com --path="/etc/lego" run
```

then run `sudo bash ./getcert.sh`, the `missing` error disappeared.

However it is replaced by the other error:

```
 Error presenting token: Zone mycompany.com. not found in CloudFlare for domain _acme-challenge.about.mycompany.com.
```

How can fix this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Did you get your API Key for your domain on Cloudflare?

If you don't know how, here is the graphical tutorial:

**Step 1: Click "Get Your API Key" on the Cloudflare main page after login**

[image]

**Step 2: Click "View" to view your API Key (Global or Domain-Specific)**

[image]

**Step 3: Fill in the credentials in the command**

```
CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=youremail@example.com
CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=yourcloudfalreAPIKey
lego --dns cloudflare --domains yourdomain.com \
  --email youremail@example.com --path="/etc/lego" run
```

Comment: The key should be 'Global API key', right?

Comment: @AnthonyKong: in the case of generating a TLS cert, just use the Origin CA Key.

Comment: @AnthonyKong: You will also need to change the domain name after the `--domains` option. Don't just copy and paste the whole thing. I am pretty sure that your domain isn't named `mycompany.com`.

Comment: @AnthonyKong: see the update.